I want help on how to remove an element when the mouse is scrolled and return an element when the mouse is scrolled away javascript
<div>one</div>
<div>two</div>
<div>three</div>
  <script>

function mouseOver() {
    console.log(this.id);
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
}
var list = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
    list[i].addEventListener("mouseover", mouseOver);
}


   </script>

I want help on how to remove an element when the mouse is scrolled and return an element when the mouse is scrolled away  javascript
